# Chrome Devtools empty file-list

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I need to inspect the website but my scripts are not listed.
[image]

I already tried to uninstalled chrome and resintalled it again.

If I pause javascript and trigger any javascript action it opens a VM-version of jquery but I need the real file, not the vm-loaded one.

Any idea?
A but or not? 
Any workaround?

Comment: Can you say more about your setup? Are you using something like Webpack? Have you checked if the jQuery file is part of a Chrome extension?

Comment: Webpack does not give empty sources-list. Chrome extensions give not empty sources-list.

Comment: @MattZeunert As i wrote, this is a fresh installation.

Comment: The interesting thing is that it's not even showing the domain node. The (index), which is just Chrome saying it's loaded an index of some sorts but doesn't know the actual extension, is in `top`. I stepped through the UI building for the Sources in DevTools using `example.com` and I found where it's adding the node for me: http://i.imgur.com/1KJRfMF.png. It might be worth stepping though using your own app and see where it's failing.

Comment: @Gideon You maybe can reproduce it. I followed http://www.sotacms.com/USE

Comment: @PeterRader Interestingly, it works fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/n4FpmuH.png. Try creating a new profile in Chrome. Click your name at the top right of screen, switch person, add a person and do not login to your Google account. See what happens when you view the Sources then. This would rule out user Chrome extensions and settings.

Comment: @Gideon That worked for me. I created a new windows-system-profile, logged into the new profile and started chrome and debugged the localhost-website. I think its a bug. Could you design this informations as an answer? btw, the incognito-mode also gives me the sources-list in the original profile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the discussion from the comments above, the issue was unrelated to the web app but the environment in which the Chrome instance was run in. It was likely a Chrome Extension or modified setting that caused this misbehaviour.

The resolution was to create a new Chrome Profile, since extensions and settings are not shared between profile instances. The next step may be to identify the particular extension or plugin at fault to avoid this happening again.