# Error message on Chrome devtools: GET http://localhost/sw.js net::ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-devtools

Every time I run a local project on Google Chrome and inspect it with developer tools, I see this error. It doesn't really affect any functionality of my application, but it's annoying.

The message will show from time to time, so that if I let the tab running for a while, the message appears multiple times.

**Environment**

I'm on Windows 10, running it on Google Chrome 51.0.2704.106 m.

**Serving**

I'm serving it from the command line with PHP-CLI (7.0.5) with the following command:

```
php -S localhost:8888
```

**Code**

All the code for this dummy project is this following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Error message</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>Hello error message.</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Developer tools: Console tab**

Here is the output at Console tab on the developer tools:

[image: Console output]

**Developer tools: Network tab**

Here is the output at Network tab on the developer tools:

[image: Network requests]

Comment: how are you hosting it?

Comment: `php -S localhost:8888`

Comment: What do you see in the "Network" tab of developer tools? This should tell you which file caused the request to be made.

Comment: @charlesrockbass where's the doc for that flag, i've never seen it before

Comment: @DanielA.White What flag do you mean?

Comment: I'll update the question with code and additional info.

Comment: the `-S` flag for `php`.

Comment: @DanielA.White — http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php

Comment: It looks like `sw.js` could be referring to a Service Worker. Do you have any other Chrome Extensions or apps running that could be trying to register a Service Worker with your app?

Comment: I updated the question with additional info and screenshots.

Comment: @Gideon I've now deactivated every single Chrome extension to be sure about it, also there's no other app related to it running at the moment. The error message continues to appear.

Comment: @charlesrockbass Try using a new Chrome Profile (click name at the top > Switch person > Add person), close all other instances of Chrome and load the page. This would ensure no user setting or extension/plugin is interfering.

Comment: @Gideon It worked. Running Chrome as guest or in private mode, the error does not happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my suggestion in comments, the issue was likely another app running (e.g. Chrome Extension) trying to request a Service Worker from the page. Using a different Chrome Profile isolated the application from 3rd party extensions, plugins and user settings, thereby preventing the issue.

This is similar to [another issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38570247/1814840) I found yesterday, and as recommended there, you probably would want to bring back extensions/plugins one by one and identify which one was causing the issue.